# Google Analytics API: Finding user age bracket and gender information

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to find the age bracket and gender information of my users using Google Analytics API using PHP. This is the query I tried running:

```
function user_gender(&$analytics, $profileId) {

  $optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:userGender',
    );

  return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '30daysAgo',
      'today',
      'ga:users',
      $optParams    
    );
}
```

However, the above query doesn't return anything. I have used the `users` metric along with the `userGender` dimension. What seems to be wrong with my query?

Comment: Assuming you have enabled demographic and interest reports in your Google analytics and added the extra code to your website your request should work.  try testing it in the query explorer https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/  and try yesterday not today it might not be done processing the data.